# How to display results of intermediate transformations of streaming query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am implementing one usecase to try-out Spark Structured Streaming API.
The source data is read from Kafka topic and after applying some transformations, results written to console.

I want to print the intermediate output along with the final results of the structured streaming query.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    val trips = getTaxiTripDataframe() //this function consumes kafka topic and desrialize the byte array to create dataframe with required columns

    val filteredTrips = trips.filter(col("taxiCompany").isNotNull && col("pickUpArea").isNotNull)

    val output = filteredTrips
      .groupBy("taxiCompany","pickupArea")
      .agg(Map("pickupArea" -> "count"))

    val query = output.writeStream.format("console")
      .option("numRows","50")
      .option("truncate","false")
      .outputMode("update").start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

I want to print 'filteredTrips' dataframe on console. I tried using .show() method of dataframe, but as it is a dataframe created on streaming data, it is throwing below exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Is there any other work around?

Comment: Any reason for `agg(Map("pickupArea" -> "count"))`? Just curious.

Comment: I am using taxi trips dataset, where each record represents one trip. It has fields like taxiCompany, pickUpArea, startTime etc. So, with above code snippet, calculating _number of trips started from particular area for taxis of particular company_. Just to experiment with aggregations using structured streaming.

Comment: It'd be more clear if you simply used `count("pickupArea")` (unless you're about to calculate multiple aggregations and in a more generic / dynamic way).

Comment: Yes, I am performing some other aggregations as well. And I found the Map() syntax easier for adding more aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create two streams (I am using Spark 2.4.3)

```
val filteredTrips = trips.filter(col("taxiCompany").isNotNull && col("pickUpArea").isNotNull)
val query1 = filteredTrips
      .format("console")
      .option("numRows","50")
      .option("truncate","false")
      .outputMode("update").start()

val query2 = filteredTrips
      .groupBy("taxiCompany","pickupArea")
      .agg(Map("pickupArea" -> "count"))
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("numRows","50")
      .option("truncate","false")
      .outputMode("update").start()

query1.awaitTermination()
query2.awaitTermination()
```